# Why is the VC dimension different on intervals and half intervals?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory, vc-dimension

As I read [this lecture](http://www.kddresearch.org/Courses/Spring-2007/CIS830/Lectures/Lecture-25-20070315.pdf) for being familiar with VC dimension we find on p. 8:

> VC(half intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ ) = 1    ....  no subset of size 2 can be shattered
>
> VC(intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ ) = 2         ....  no subset of size 3

It's not clear to me. I read [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29) about the difference of  Half Interval and Interval and why VC dimension are different.

For example can this set be half intervals or intervals?

$$
\{ (-\infty \le x \le a) \, \left|\, a \in \mathbb{R} \right. \}
$$

Any direction or hint on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume a half interval $I_a$ is always of the form

$$ \{(-\infty \leq x \leq a) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\} $$

This means that all points equal or smaller than $a$ belong to the interval. Now, choose any set $S = \{y,z\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $y < z$. $S$ is not shattered, since it is impossible to find a half interval $I_a$ such that $S \cap I_a = \{z\}$ (if $z$ is included in the intersection, than $y$ has to be included as well).

When we consider intervals $I_{a,b} = \{(a \leq x \leq b \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ in contrast to half intervals, we are able to find an interval $I_{a,b}$ such that $I_{a,b} \cap S = \{z\}$ (as well as for all other subsets of $S$). This makes the difference in the VC dimension.